# PHP: get contents of li's within ul

Tags: php

Ok I have about 12 pages included in a php page that look like this:

```
<a name="1"> </a>
<h2>Unit 1: Awareness of employment in the creative media sector</h2>
<p />
<h3> Learning outcomes:</h3>
<ul class="outcomes">
<li class="n1">Know about employment status in the Creative Media sector</li>
<li class="n2">Understand the Creative Media employment market place</li>
<li class="n3">Be able to promote self</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul class="files">
```

I want to be able to store the contents of the li's in an array, so I want to find grab the contents of each li within an ul with the class "outcomes" and push to array.

Is this possible? I have heard of Xpath but it looks like jibberish to me, can anyone explain this more simply with some straightforward php or push me in the right direction for xpathing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a PHP DOM parser such as [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

Answer (score 7):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_page_here);

$xp  = new XPath($dom);

$classes = $xp->query('//ul[@class="outcomes"]/li');

$class_info = array();
foreach($classes as $class) {
    $class_info[] = $class->nodeValue;
}
```

Not very gibberish-ish. If it helps, you can think of the DOM model as a file system representing your document, and XPath is a directory path specification to navigate that file system.

Comment: Thanks im sure this works from all the thumbs up its getting but I am having trouble installing the Xpath class. I downloaded xpath.class.php from sourceforge and try including it but it still says 'Fatal error: Class 'XPath' not found'. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Just needed to change XPath($dom) to DOMXpath($dom) but the $class_info array is empty.